# How exactly GetRequestAsync works?

Tags: c#, rest, asynchronous, httpwebrequest

i think i'm missing something about how HttpWebRequest works via streaming when uploading large files.
basicly, i found out that i receive timeout exception when sending large files to the server, so a post suggested to do it via Async and handle the timeout myself.

The thing is, that after debugging, i found out that "GetRequestStreamAsync" method, and writing to it does nothing at the server side, the server is called only when doing GetResponseAsync

so my question is:

**- code marked as //1 - it writes the file to the request stream, but i don't see that the memory is increasing, or the server even getting any request - where does the streaming go to?**

This is basicly my code:

```
            HttpWebRequest request = RESTUtils.InitializeRequest(...);

            request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
            request.ContentLength = i_InputStream.Length;
            request.Timeout = 5000;  

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStreamWithTimeout())
            {
               if (requestStream != null) //1
               {
                  // We will write the stream to the request
                  byte[] buffer = new byte[UPLOAD_FILE_BUFFER_SIZE];
                  int read = i_InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                  while (read > 0)
                  {
                     requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, read);                         
                     read = i_InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                  }
               }
            }

            using (var response = request.GetResponseWithTimeout(-1))
            {
               using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
               {

               }
            }

public static class WebRequestExtensions
   {
      public static Stream GetRequestStreamWithTimeout(
          this WebRequest request,
          int? millisecondsTimeout = null)
      {
         return AsyncToSyncWithTimeout(
             request.BeginGetRequestStream,
             request.EndGetRequestStream,
             millisecondsTimeout ?? request.Timeout);
      }

      public static WebResponse GetResponseWithTimeout(
          this HttpWebRequest request,
          int? millisecondsTimeout = null)
      {
         return AsyncToSyncWithTimeout(
             request.BeginGetResponse,
             request.EndGetResponse,
             millisecondsTimeout ?? request.Timeout);
      }

      private static T AsyncToSyncWithTimeout<T>(
          Func<AsyncCallback, object, IAsyncResult> begin,
          Func<IAsyncResult, T> end,
          int millisecondsTimeout)
      {
         var iar = begin(null, null);
         if (!iar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(millisecondsTimeout))
         {
            var ex = new TimeoutException();
            throw new WebException(ex.Message, ex, WebExceptionStatus.Timeout, null);
         }
         return end(iar);
      }
   }
```

Thanks!

== Edit 9/9/15 ==

Something even weirder happens, i'm attaching breakpoint right after GetResponseAsync, then i see that the server receives the call.
after that, i'm closing the process of the client -> the server is uploading the file successfully.

this happens also if i do "Abort". 
anyone knows why?

Comment: AsyncToSyncWithTimeout fails to call end in case of a timeout. That's a resource leak.

Comment: Why did you switch to async? That has nothing to do with streaming out timeouts.

Comment: Use  [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: @usr im aware of the leak, its just a sample code. And i couldnt stream large files, the client timeout just popped out. Async doesnt use that timeout so i went to this direction.

Comment: @Eser i prefer staying with this method, i searched for the Httpclient and saw that all implementations use multipart forms, but i dont use forms at server side, its plain streaming.

Comment: @ArielB Then you should search more.... `multipart forms` is just a single use of it. In fact it has a nicer API than HttpWebRequest, with full support of async/await

Comment: @Eser we'll keep it as a technical debt, we can't really change our entire REST client right now.
The question is still opened though, where is the buffer going when streaming the request async

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the old-style begin/end async pattern, you should consider switching to [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) which would greatly simplify your code.

You would then set the `Timeout` property against the request to a large value to accommodate your waiting time; then instead of using the callback-based async code, you could just do:

```
var request = SomeMethodToCreateRequest();
request.Timeout = int.MaxValue; // (don't do this)
var response = await request.GetResponse();
```

The timeout should be respected internally, and you get to simplify your code.

Comment: I dont want to set large timeout. The server is streamed using wcf. Large timeout will cause delay if server is not available.